# Vue: add an item to a list

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm a beginner studying Vue Js. I'm trying to add an item to a list but it doesn't work. My list is in the state of the store, and the function to add a new element is in the mutations.
Please is the function that allows to add a new element badly coded or the error is elsewhere.

Please help me.

There is my Vuex store code

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    produits: [
            {text: "ananas", checked: true},
            {text: "banane", checked: false},
            {text: "orange", checked: true},
    ],
    newProduit: ''
  },
  mutations: {
    addItem: function(ecrit) {

      ecrit= this.state.newProduit.trim();
      if(ecrit) {
        this.state.produits.push({
          text:ecrit,
          checked: false
        });
      }
    }
  },
  actions: {},
  modules: {},
});
```

There is my component code

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-input-group class="mt-3">
      <b-form-input></b-form-input>
      <b-input-group-append>
        <b-button variant="info" v-on:click="ajoutElement">Ajouter</b-button>
      </b-input-group-append>
    </b-input-group>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    ajoutElement: {
      get() {
         return this.$store.state.produits;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$store.commit('addItem',value)
      }
    }     
  }
}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Where is your action ? Using vuex just make sure you add all required standard principle of state management.

Answer (score 2):

You should add action for each of the action that you are making from component.

I have added an action **addItemAction**. You can see this for reference, Ideally you should have action-> commits-> mutation

In a large application, you can even create separate modules should have function for each of modules to perform  action-> commits-> mutation

**component**

```
set(value) {
        this.$store.dispatch('addItemAction',value); // Dispatch action with name and params.
      }
```

Update vuex store now

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
state: {
produits: [
        {text: "ananas", checked: true},
        {text: "banane", checked: false},
        {text: "orange", checked: true},
],
newProduit: ''
},
mutations: {
addItem: function(ecrit) {

  ecrit= this.state.newProduit.trim();
  if(ecrit) {
    this.state.produits.push({
      text:ecrit,
      checked: false
    });
  }
}
 },


actions: {
  addItemAction: function(context, ecrit){
    context.commit('addItem', ecrit); // Commit from here.
  }
},
modules: {},
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. 
I added the action but when I enter an item and press the submit button, the item is not added to the list

Comment: I shared the approach and sample code, can you create stackblitz or you can take a details look in the doc https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions

Dispatching action from components.

Comment: Okay, but please i need a mentor, an expert in Vue Js to whom I can refer when I am stuck and when I need precise explanations.
Please would you like to be my mentor in Vue Js.

It will help me a lot to evolve in Vue Js

Comment: Definitely, I believe in sharing knowledge and learning experience. Connect wit me here https://www.linkedin.com/in/abhinavkumar985

Comment: Thanks in advance, i Just send you invitation on LinkedIn(venceslas koukou my LinkedIn profil).